# How to get the real client port via IBM HTTP Server

Tags: java, jsp

I just have a jsp file, print

```
request.getRemoteIp();
request.getRemotePort();
```

And I can get the real client ip, but the port is always wrong.
The Server Environment is IBM Websphere and IBM HTTP Server (IHS60)

From the iptrace, I get the packet data..

From the Client to Server, the port is 13944 to 80 (http port is 80). So the client port is 13944.

Then via HTTP, in the jsp, I invoke an API on another server, the port is 48186 to 9082.

Actually, 
`request.getRemoteIp();` I really get the client ip.

but
`request.getRemotePort();` I get the port number is **48185**, it seems be IHS port.

How can I get my real client port, please?

Thanks very much.